# Angular Directive not executing on UI Bootstrap Modal open

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a one-page site that I am building out and this is my first time using Angular on a site. Building it on top of Laravel too for the backend but that is beyond the scope of this question.

I need to be able to open a modal on a main page view which will add a new resource (e.g. a new client) or edit a resource. I want to somehow get the form's html inside the modal body when the `$uibModal.open()`'s controller is called and set the `$scope.modalBody` equal to the injected `items.modalBody` (the only way this works is if I use:

`$scope.modalBody = $sce.trustAsHtml(items.modalBody);`

The only problem now is that anything inside the HTML body, Angular will not use it's magic and do any data-binding. It is still in the raw form of

`{{ object.property }}` or since I'm using Laravel and avoiding conflict with the Blade template engine:

`<% object.property %>`

See screenshot:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ByHd.png)

I have been banging my head against the wall on this one...I have tried putting `$scope.$apply()` in my directive and my controller, neither of which worked. I have a feeling that is the source of my problem though. I have also tried making the html just a `<new-client></new-client>` directive and using `templateUrl: 'views/clients/add.php'` which would be ideal, but the template is not being included inside the `<new-client></new-client>`.

I'm using ui-bootstrap 0.14.3 and Angular 1.4.8.

Could this be a bug? Or am I doing something wrong? Anyone have a better way of getting a form into my modal? Let me know what code you want to see so I don't clutter this post with unnecessary code blocks.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across a similar issue with using jQuery's `AJAX` to receive template strings and append it to a server.

So when HTML is added via jQuery, bound html string, etc., angular doesn't know it needs to automagically `compile` this data.

What you need to do is use the `$compile` service, to `$compile` your html and then attach the correct `$scope` to it:

```
`$compile('jQuerySelectorReturningHtmlOrAnHTMLStringThatNeedsToBeCompiled')($scope);`
```

There are [multiple examples in Angulars Documentation for $compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) that can give you an idea of what is happening. I think by what you have described the same thing is happening here in your situation.

The key is to call this $compile service function after the html has been bound to the page.

#### EDIT:

There are a few other options based on some comments, that will serve as a viable solution to rendering this content on your view. For example a directive that takes a string attribute representing the HTML string of your desired view.

## 1. Modify your directive template in the compile step:

You have the ability to modify your template before the directive compiles and binds any attributes to it, to that directives scope:

```
app.directive('myAwesomeCompileStepDirective', [myAwesomeCompileStepDirectivef]);

function myAwesomeCompileStepDirectiveFn() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    compile: function compileFn(tAttrs, tElement) {
      //Here you can access the attrs that are passed into your directive (aka html string)
      tElement.html(tAttrs['stringThatYouWantToReplaceElementWith']);

      return function linkFn(scope, element, attrs, controller, transcludeFn) {
        //if all you want to do is update the template you really don't have to do anything
        //here but I leave it defined anyways.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can view a [file I wrote for a npm component](https://github.com/TheLarkInn/moo-angular-accordion/blob/master/src/mooAccordionPanel.component.js) which uses this method to modify my directive template before it is compiled on the page & you can also view the <kbd>[codepen for the complete component](http://codepen.io/TheLarkInn/pen/xwNZag)</kbd> to see it in action.

## 2. Use $compile service to call $compile in link function using directive attrs.

In the same way as the aforementioned method, you can instead inject the `$compile` service, and call the function mentioned above. This provides a bit more work, for you but more flexibility to listen to events and perform scope based functions which is not available in the `compile` function in option 1.

Comment: This definitely sounds like a solution that is along the lines of what I'm thinking. So will `$compile($sce.trustAsHtml(items.modalBody))` return a "compiled" version of the HTML string? Or would I need to apply it to the `$scope.modalBody` property once initialized?

Comment: Yes it will. It is common to see in directives that the `element` variable provided in the link function, is assigned to the returned value of a `$compile` fn. Just make sure that you attach the appropriate scope as the second argument as an IIEF.

Comment: You're probably needing something like this: `elem.html( templateString );` then you compile it like so `$compile( elem.contents())( $scope )`.  This is being done in the `link` function on the directive BTW

Comment: Ok so I have added a plnkr for you guys to look at http://plnkr.co/edit/wtWqUkBpRo1BoCV2UH0I?p=preview hopefully you see what I do. It uses the values of `modalTitle` and `modalBody` but the directive `<new-client></new-client>` is not being "sensed" (not sure what word you would use to describe that behavior).